# Migrate a ubuntu VM on virsh to a hyperv 2012 server

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machines, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012

I have an ubuntu 13.04 server virtual machine on an ubuntu server 13.04 running libvirt 1.1.1. I want to migrate this to a hyper-v 2012 R2 server. I'm not terrible familiar with linux, and would appreciate some advice. So far, I've found https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/how-to-create-a-dupe-of-a-kvm-libvirt-virt-manager-vm which presents a way to clone the VM, which seems like a good start. Can i simply copy the VM's drive, and then create a new VM on the hyperv server with that copy? Any tips would be a great help!

Answer (score 1):

First off, download this tool:

http://www.systola.com/blog/14.01.2015/VhdTool-Is-Dead-Long-Live-VhdxTool/#.V3vdh5MrLUI

## make a directory for the virtual machine on the hyper-v 2012 vhost

```
mkdir C:\VIRTUALMACHINE
```

## smb mount the KVM file system

```
net use \\kvm-server.mydomain.com\kvm-disk-share z:
```

## change to the mounted file system

```
cd \\kvm-server.mydomain.com\kvm-disk-share
```

## copy the KVM disk to the Hyper-V server

```
copy VIRTUALMACHINE.disk C:\VIRTUALMACHINE
```

## unmount the smb mounted KVM file system

```
net use \\kvm-server.mydomain.com\kvm-disk-share /delete
```

## append a vhd header to the raw disk file

```
PS C:\disks> .\VHDToolx.exe /convert .\VIRTUALMACHINE.disk=
```

## rename the raw disk file as a .vhd file

```
PS C:\disks> ren .\VIRTUALMACHINE.disk .\rhel5.vhd
```

Comment: You will always get some weird errors doing this but this is the appropriate way. If you get any errors, post them here.

Comment: One complicating factor- the server 2012 hyperv server is command-line only, as it's the community version or whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

Configure X server to run under Hyper-V

## edit the /etc/X11/xorg.conf file

## change Section "Device" Driver to "vesa"

## change Section "Screen" DefaultDepth to 16

## change SubSection "Display" Depth to 16

## reboot to commit changes to disk

```
shutdown -r now
```

Comment: And then i can just move the drive to the VHD server and import virtual machine?

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/82ec8e41-7ac1-4166-97c3-d3dabc5ba29a/how-to-properly-move-a-vm-to-another-physical-server?forum=winserverhyperv